# Get first 3 characters of filename (REGEX)

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I'm having a trouble to get first 3 characters of filename.
I have a page with many images and i need to apply for each one a specific watermark based on prefix filename.

```
FP-filename.jpg
OU-filename.jpg
MO-filename.jpg
SD-filename.jpg
```

I have this rule wich apply watermark on all pages:

```
RewriteRule ^([^tn].*\.(jpg))$ watermark.php?image=$1&watermark=watermark.png [NC]
```

But when i try to apply a rule based on prefix no watermark is visible:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})-(.+?\.jpg)$ watermark.php?image=$1-$2&watermark=$1-watermark.png [NC,L]
```

Where do I wrong?

Maybe can I solve with a specific RewriteRule line, one for each prefix?

Any help?

Comment: What should be rewritten URL with first 2/3 characters of URI?

Comment: In fact, with RewriteRule i try to check image prefix and apply watermark. I'm on wrong way?

Comment: You regex works correctly as shown [here](http://regexr.com?37a82). What happens if you change the replacement, so that it just uses watermark.png - does watermark.png show up correctly as usual?

Comment: @OGHaza, none show up. Only with first rule i can show watermark...

Comment: Well I see no reason for it not to work other than if your watermark.php is wrong in some way.

Comment: Strange, BTW: First rule working, there is a way to create 2 rules and tell him to get image prefix? Like something...

RewriteRule ^([^AA-].*\.(jpg))$ watermark.php?image=$1&watermark=aa-watermark.png [NC]

RewriteRule ^([^BB-].*\.(jpg))$ watermark.php?image=$1&watermark=bb-watermark.png [NC]